# Associação entre 2 tabelas

Tags: php

Estou com um problema ao buscar dados de 2 tabelas, ambas associadas.
Quando vou no browser e coloco o *controller* e depois o método, ele me aparece com essa mensagem `Array()`. Alguém poderia me dizer qual o problema com meu código?

```
    public function categoria($slug_categoria = null){

    //Recebendo os dados das categorias
    $menu_categoria['categorias'] = $this->db->get('categorias')->result();

    //Criando querys SQL com JOIN usando o Active Record
    $this->db->select('r.id_receita, r.nome, r.slug_receita, r.foto, c.categoria');
    $this->db->from('receitas r');
    $this->db->join('categorias c', 'c.id_categoria = r.categoria', 'INNER');
    $this->db->where('c.slug_categoria', $slug_categoria);
    $this->db->order_by('r.nome', 'ASC');

    $receita['receitas'] = $this->db->get()->result();

    //Carregando as views 
    $this->load->view('html_header');
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('menu_category', $menu_categoria);
    $this->load->view('categoria', $receita);
    $this->load->view('footer');
    $this->load->view('html_footer');       
}
```

---

Tentei isto:

```
<?php
echo heading("Receitas Deliciosas", 2);
if (count($receitas) > 0) {
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        echo heading($receitas[0]->categoria, 3);
        foreach ($receitas as $item):
            ?>
            <li class="gradiente1 radious">
                <?php
                echo anchor("receita/" . $item->slug_receita, $item->nome);
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php
}else {
    echo "Nenhuma receita encontrada nesta categoria.";
}
?>
```

Fiz o loop e ele executou o echo "Nenhuma receita encontrada...".

Comment: Conseguir resolver o problema, obrigado pelo ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Isso porque você está dando um echo em uma variável do tipo array. Como ele não é "printável", o php joga na tela o "tipo dele".

Na view, no lugar de

```
echo $receitas
```

Coloque

```
var_dump( $receitas );
```

E você verá suas receitas. Obviamente, isso é apenas para debugar. Para listar as receitas, você precisará iterar em um loop, usando o foreach, por exemplo.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda. Fiz o que pediu, ai ele me retornou isso da variável array (size=0) empty. Sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: Isso significa que a variável está sendo populada com um array vazio. Ou seja, seu SQL não está trazendo nada no banco de dados. Você não tem nenhum registro no banco de dados, ou sua consulta não está correta e não está trazendo nada.